# Voltar ao slide inicial JS

Tags: javascript, html

Bom dia! Desde já peço desculpa pelo título mas não achei nenhum melhor...
Bom eu tenho uma página que mostra o conteúdo em "*slides*", ou seja de início mostra o *slide* 1, e ao carregar na **seta seguinte** mostra o próximo (*slide* 2).

Para deixar mais claro vejam aqui - https://jsfiddle.net/f319gbwk/8/ (expandir o quadrado do resultado).
O que eu pretendia agora é que depois de passar o último slide, em vez de ficar aquela página em branco, voltasse ao **1 *slide***, eu experimentei com `while`, `for` mas não consegui implementar... 
Obrigada  a quem poder ajudar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está quase lá! Se tivesses animações, terias de mudar um pouco o que já tens, mas, como (pelo menos para já) não tens, basta mudares as tuas condições que mudar a var `current` e adicionar um `else`.

Quando queres fazer slide a direita, verificas se já estás no último slide, e caso estejas, mandas de novo para o primeiro `current = 0`. Quando fazes pra esquerda, é a verificacao oposta, se estás no primeiro slide, mandas para o último, `current = sliderImages.length - 1` (-1 pois o array tem indice 0).

Fica assim.

```
//Mostrar anterior
function slideLeft() {
    reset();
    if (current > 0) { // aqui fica igual
        current--;
    } else { // mas caso current seja 0, entao é o primeiro slide, temos de mandar para o último
        current = sliderImages.length - 1;
    }

    sliderImages[current].style.display = "block";
}

// Mostrar seguinte
function slideRight() {
    reset();
    if (current < sliderImages.length - 1) { // aqui temos de adicionar o -1 para comparar que current é 3 (posicao do ultimo slide no array)
        current++;
    } else { // e adicionamos o else para mandar para o primeiro
        current = 0;
    }

    sliderImages[current].style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Perfeito!! Muito obrigada, afinal era tão simples, e eu compliquei tudo, ainda por mais tentei dessa maneira, mas não consegui porque não me passou pela cabeça o `-1` na função `slideRight()`, então presumi logo que não ia funcionar! Muito obrigada!!